# How many colonies can be put into a sector?

Tags: stellaris

So far I've planned on only putting as many colonies into one sector as my directly controlled planets allowed (i.e. if I can control 5 colonies directly, I only put 5 colonies in a sector).

Is this actually correct or is there no limit for sector size or even a fixed one independent from the directly controllable planets statistic?

I'm talking about an effective limit here without incurring penalties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently there isn't a limit to how many planets can be in a sector.

That said sector governor AI will not manage sector very well. Hopefully will be better eventually with more work on AI. This info is current for 1.02 Hotfix.

So you just have to find a balance between how many planets per sector vs one large single sector.

You many want a sector dedicated to research. One dedicated to mineral production etc...

Comment: I haven't run into a limit myself, but there's a technology that says +1 Sector Size, and I have no idea what that means if there's no limit.

Comment: My answer comes from one of the live stream that Paradox did. You are right there are technologies that raise both number of max sector and core planets but otherwise they don't affect sector's max size. Source: https://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/index.php?threads/planet-limits-in-sectors.920663/

Comment: You're saying there's a limit on the number of sectors? Maybe that's what those technologies do.

Comment: @DCShannon you can see it just to the left of the create sector button.  In this screenshot, they have 2 of a possible 3 sectors created: http://i.imgur.com/HFNpftt.jpg

Comment: Seems like this is another incomplete mechanic then; like slaves never rebelling. Makes little sense to me to be able to create 10+ sectors, when it's unlimited anyway.

Comment: "Hopefully will be better eventually with more work on AI."
According to the dev diary # 33, there will be improvement on AI, notably the Sector AI with the 1.1 update - “Clarke” scheduled for the end of May. https://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/index.php?threads/stellaris-dev-diary-33-the-maiden-voyage.932668/